# C# - How to inherit documentation from hidden methods (new keyword)

Tags: c#, documentation

Is there a way not to hide the documentation of the original method in the child class? For example;

```
    public class Parent
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Boo!!!
        /// </summary>
        public void Foo()
        {
            // ... code here
        }
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        // inheritdoc doesn't work here

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public new void Foo()
        {
            base.Foo();
            // ... additional logic here
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should not, it will be Absolutely Wrong if it does. You are making a new implementation of Foo so new summary.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz Yes, but the logic is the same. There's just some additional thing that I want to implement just for that Child class. What Foo does doesn't change here. So, I need to write the same documentation again?

Comment: It's not the same constructor

Comment: Ok, so, there's no way to inherit documentation from hidden methods

Comment: When you use the `new` keyword, you are declaring a different method with the same name. It's not like when you use the `overrides` keyword, in which case you're declaring the same method with a different implementation. Because it's a different method, it doesn't make sense for it to have the same documentation. It's the case that people tend to use `new` when what they actually want to use is `overrides` but the original method isn't `virtual`, but that was not the intention.

Answer (score 2):

As Muhammad just said: By declaring a method with the `new` keyword, you basically create a new method signature, that is not related to the old method in any way. A `virtual` method however `overrides` the old method instead of covering it up. Therefore overriding a method will inherit its documentation.

```
public class Parent
{

    /// <summary>
    ///  a classic method documentation
    /// </summary>
    public void Test1()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// a virtual method documentation
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void Test2()
    {

    }
}


public class Child : Parent
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    // does not inherit documentation
    public new void Test1()
    {
        base.Test1();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    // does inherit documentation
    public override void Test2()
    {
        base.Test2();
    }
}
```